# paying a tip on a service or for a service?

Tags: grammar, idioms

Is it grammatical to say "pay a tip on a service" or should I use "for" instead? Which one is more grammatical? Also, do you say "pay a tip on the 20$"? If it's for? Then how do you say "pay a tip on the 20$ for the service provided"? It sounds weird to say "pay a tip on the 20$ on the service provided".

Comment: Usually write $20 when you say "20 dollars"  (illogical, but that is the rule), and technically you don't pay a tip for the service.  The tip is an extra, optional payment.

Comment: But it's common **to tip a waiter for good service**.

Comment: In the UK we usually give a tip rather than pay it or we tip the waiter.

Comment: By the way, we normally put the dollar sign before the amount, like **$20**.

Answer (score 2):

“For” would be correct.

Also, I think the way you express it isn’t too idiomatic. Though technically correct, I wouldn’t say it as paying a tip “on the $20.” I would say something like:

> I paid $20 plus a tip for (the) service.

Further, as it’s generally understood that the tip is for service, it could also be said more simply as:

> I paid $20 plus a tip.

Saying “paid a tip **on** the $20” does make sense, and expresses the idea that a tip is usually calculated as a percentage of the amount you paid for the goods.

Comment: I just don't understand why those posting comments don't bother to agree with your answer as I did.....